# To show that for some $\epsilon > 0$, $\{x \in X : d(x,A) < \epsilon \ \} \subset U$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $A$ be compact and $U$ be open in a metric space $(X,d)$ such that $A \subset U$. To show that for some $\epsilon > 0$, $\{x \in X : d(x,A) < \epsilon \ \} \subset U$.

Let us take a set of all points which are in $U$ but not in $A$. Then for a point say $x$ in the set, $d(x,A) >0$. Then we find all such distances for all the points in the set and consider the minimal distances among them and take it as our $\epsilon$. Then $\{x \in X : d(x,A) < \epsilon \ \} \subset U$ holds true.

Is the above logic  correct?

Comment: Consider $A=[0,1]$ and $U=(-1,2).$ Then the infimum of the distances is zero. This can't be used as $\epsilon.$ You need to make use of the compactness of $A.$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is not true, then $\exists$ a sequence $x_n \in X\setminus U$ such that $d(x_n,A) < 1/n$. Choose $y_n \in A$ such that $d(x_n,y_n) = d(x_n,A)$ [this is possible since $A$ is compact]. By choosing a subsequence if necessary, assume that $y_n \to y \in A$. Now consider
$$
d(x_n,y) \leq d(x_n,y_n) + d(y_n,y) \to 0
$$
Since $U$ is open, $y\in X\setminus U$, and so $A\cap (X\setminus U) \neq \emptyset$.